# Core Data sqlite file growing

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite, core-data

I have a synchronization process and Im using `Core Data` to store a lot of information. Several times I downloaded the real `SQLite` database file with the organizer to check if the data is correct.

Some days ago I recongized that the size difference of two `SQLite` files was huge. One file was 80MB, the other file about 100MB. As I checked out the data in it with a `SQLite`viewer there was no difference. The same tables, same indexes, same rows. How can that be? Is is is possible that some data is still in the file when I delete objects over `Core Data`?

EDIT:

The solution is an option flag which can be inserted in an option NSDictionary and added as parameter to the addPersistentStore method.

```
NSSQLiteManualVacuumOption
Option key to rebuild the store file, forcing a database wide defragmentation when the store is added to the coordinator.

This invokes SQLite's VACUUM command. It is ignored by stores other than the SQLite store.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sqlite does not proactively return unused disk space as it deletes data, for performance reasons.  This could be why you see the difference.  See this link for more info:

[SQLite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q12)

Comment: Thx! That helped me a lot. I found the solution with your information in the Apple reference. Accepted it :)